# Apache symlink 404 error

Tags: apache, cpanel, root, symlink

I'm having an issue with apache2 handling symlinks.

Here's the situation:

I have some files at **/source_folder** (access is: **root:group**)

I created a symlink to **/home/user/public_html/target_folder** (symlink)

`ln -s /source_folder /home/user/public_html/target_folder`

The created symlink has access **root:root** and **everything works** great.
Also user and root both are in a group and soruce file has is also set to group.

But when I change the symlink owner to "**user:user**" or "**user:group**" suddenly **everything stops working**.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Here's the log from apache:

```
[HTAccess] Failed to open [/home/user/public_html/target_folder/.htaccess]: Permission denied
[INFO] File not found [/home/user/public_html/target_folder/index.php]
[INFO] Cannot found appropriate handler for [/index.php]
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

[Also the webpage shows this (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fbqE.png)

I tried **restarting** the server, changing settings for **SymLinkIfOwnerMatch** and so many other things.

Can anyone help? I'll be thankful.

Comment: [Check this answer](https://superuser.com/q/244245/169705).

Comment: @MattClark Thanks. I just tried that. the htaccess error gone away but other exists.

Comment: Cool. What else for errors? `Cannot found appropriate handler for [/index.php]` means PHP is not properly setup for apache. [Check here](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.debian.php) for setting up PHP on a Linux system.

Comment: @MattClark I have 5 running websites already on that server. also this is just a folder. other folders are ok. Now only this error exists: `[INFO] File not found [/home/user/public_html/target_folder/index.php]`

Comment: Oops, I should have read the question more clearly; `But when I change the symlink owner to user:group suddenly everything stops working.` - then don't do this unless absolutely needed, I've never done it and always leave them as root:root; when using symlinks, the permissions of the target directory are used. I did [just find this though](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33183/36669).

Comment: @MattClark Yes usually using root:root is not a problem. But I have a api script for cpanel that creates these symlinks automatically and has no access to root to change them root:root so it will be user:user. And it does not work :( Thanks for help. <3